# How to access form action from a Html tag via a controller class

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I have a portfolio website created in layeredMVC using Eclipse. I am using Java and sqlite database to retrieve data and display it on the website.
I wanted to add an admin page to edit and update some details from the website. I am having trouble accessing the form action via the controller class.

I'm not using Tomcat servers, as a result, I can't use Sevlet functions. I'm using a separate class called server, where I am using HttpServer and HttpHandler to perform the rest of the actions.

can some one help me figure out?

This is what i have so far:
public class LoginController {

```
private final LoginLogic loginLogic;

public LoginController(LoginRepository loginRepository) {
    this.loginLogic = new LoginLogic(loginRepository);
}

public String login(String username, String password) {
    boolean isAuthenticated = loginLogic.authenticateUser(username, password);

    if (isAuthenticated) {
        // Redirect to a success page or perform other actions
        return "redirect:/about";
        
    } else {
        // Show login page with an error message
        return "forward:/login.html?error=1";
    }
}

public View index() {
    // Add logic for handling the login page rendering, if needed
    return new View("login");// Assuming "login" is the view name
}
```

}